# How to keep multiple buttons border changed when I clicked the button in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

First of all, thank you for helping me out! I am trying to change my button border color when I liked the button by using focus and active like this

```
button {
            margin: 5px;
            width: 44px;
            height: 32px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            border-radius: 15%;

            &:active,
            &:focus {
              border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

However, when I click one button, it changes the button's border color as well. However, when I click the other button, it changes the border color but the first clicked button border change to originally. It means that I can only change one of the buttons' border colors. How can I keep several buttons' border color and furthermore, when I re-click the same button I want to change it to the original.

[image]

As an above image, I can only change one button border color.

```
updateSize = e => {
    const { history, location } = this.props;
    const name = e.currentTarget.value;

    const currentQueryString = location.search;
    const url = new URLSearchParams(currentQueryString);

    const isSizeExist = url.getAll('size').includes(name);

    if (isSizeExist) {
      filterSizeExist();
    } else {
      filterSizeNotExist();
    }

    applyQueryStringToURL();
    function filterSizeExist() {
      const sizes = url.getAll('size');
      const isCertainSizeExist = sizes.includes(name);

      if (isCertainSizeExist) {
        const filteredSizes = sizes.filter(size => size !== name);

        url.delete('size');
        filteredSizes.forEach(size => url.append('size', size));
      }
    }

    function filterSizeNotExist() {
      url.append('size', name);
    }

    function applyQueryStringToURL() {
      const qs = url.toString();
      const query = `${url.toString() ? '?' : ''}` + qs;

      history.push('/products' + query);
    }
    this.setState({ selectedItemSize: url.getAll('size') });
  };

<div className="sizes">
              <div className="HorizontalLine" />
              <span>사이즈</span>
              <div className="sizeLists">
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="230" key="1">
                  230
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="235" key="2">
                  235
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="240" key="3">
                  240
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="245" key="4">
                  245
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="250" key="5">
                  250
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="255" key="6">
                  255
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="260" key="7">
                  260
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="265" key="8">
                  265
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="270" key="9">
                  270
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="275" key="10">
                  275
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.updateSize} value="280" key="11">
                  280
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="HorizontalLine" />
            </div>
```

Comment: Both `:active` and `:focus` can not apply to more than one element at a time. Don't use these pseudo classes, use JavaScript to toggle a "real" class on the buttons instead, and apply the formatting via that class.

Comment: There can only be one active element. In this case just add a class e.g. "active". If you want to track all the selected items use a state with an array and you add or remove the ids there when you toggle the buttons. The active class will be set, if the id is in the array ... something like array.includes(id)

Comment: create a CSS rule `.selected{/*selected border style*/}` and in JS code on button click assign/remove this class rom the button.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am just getting started learning to react so... pretty hard to understand what you guys said... but I am trying to understand what you guys said

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right you want to do something like :

1. Make borders active if i click at them once
2. Remove border when i click at them again
3. Keep up the border until i click at them again

So,

1. Use a `useState()` and a boolean(to take care of click event)
2. Whenever someone click at `btn` at once or twice , change the boolean value respectively.
3. Use `if` condition , if boolean true `className = 'bordered'` else `''`

Hope you got the Idea ! , What i wanted to say.

Comment: Yes! You're right! Thank you for helping me out! Is there any other way to use another one rather than using useState()? I couldn't resolve the useState() error for a few days...